# How to invoke a controller method after a checkbox gets clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to make `CheckBox` invoke a controller method on click just like it does `ActionLink`? Basically, I want to replace this `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Switch status", "SwitchTaskIsComplete", "Task", new {
    taskId = task.TaskId, 
    isComplete = !task.IsComplete, 
    userId = Model.UserId
}, null)
```

with a `@Html.CheckBox`, which invokes the same method

```
SwitchTasksIsComplete(int taskId, bool isComplete, int userId)
```

of `TaskController` and uses its `checked` property as `isComplete` parameter every time it gets clicked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the HTML `onclick` for this:

```
@Html.CheckBox("mycheckbox", new { onclick="triggerLink()" })
```

Use `@Url.Action` instead of `@Html.ActionLink` to get just the URL:

```
<script>
    function triggerLink() {
        var theUrl = '@Url.Action("SwitchTaskIsComplete", "Task", new {taskId = task.TaskId, isComplete = !task.IsComplete, userId = Model.UserId}, null)';
        window.location = theUrl;
    }
</script>
```

---

You could also put the whole expression inline in the attribute:

```
@{
    var url = Url.Action("SwitchTaskIsComplete", "Task", new {taskId = task.TaskId, isComplete = !task.IsComplete, userId = Model.UserId}, null);
}
@Html.CheckBox("mycheckbox", new { onclick="window.location = '" + url + "'" })
```

Comment: @McGarnagle how would I add text next to checkbox for example `"Unread messages [CheckBox]"`, is there something like : `@Html.CheckBox("Unread messages", "mycheckbox", new { onclick="triggerLink()" })` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    var url = Url.Action("action", "controller");
}
<label class="some-style">
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="window.location='@url'" />
   <span class="Some-other-style">Your Label</span>
</label>
```

This solution implements a regular html checkbox expression with a url action, whenever the textbox is clicked, the action is submitted to the controller. You can also include a value in the case you need to know the checkbox's state.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.